# Is there a better way to design this RPG Inventory?

Tags: android, arrays, andengine, inventory

This is what I came up with to get by, but it's terrible, and I know there has to be a better way. I would eventually like the Item in inventory to have the corresponding texture to display an icon for it.

```
ButtonSprite btn = new ButtonSprite(50, 280,
            AssetLoaderUtil.yourTextureRegion,
            mContext.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pAreaTouchEvent,
                final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            switch (pAreaTouchEvent.getAction()) {
            case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // do action when button pressed down.
                break;
            case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // do action when button pressed up.

                //
                // UserData.getInstance().unlockNextLevel();
                //

                if (inventory == false) {

                    // showInventory();
                    inventory = true;

                    inventoryRect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 460, 260,
                            mContext.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

                    inventoryRect.setColor(0, 0, 0, 0.9f);

                    hud.attachChild(inventoryRect);
                    inventoryRect.setVisible(true);
                    inventoryRect.setZIndex(11);

                    inventRect = true;

                    Text inventoryTitleText = new Text(5, 0,
                            AssetLoaderUtil.mFontMENU, "Inventory",
                            mContext.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                    inventoryTitleText.setPosition(200, 20);
                    inventoryTitleText.setColor(Color.WHITE);

                    inventoryRect.attachChild(inventoryTitleText);

                    /*
                     * Text itemText = new Text(5, 0,
                     * AssetLoaderUtil.mFontMENU, "Nada...",
                     * mContext.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                     * itemText.setPosition(200, 60);
                     * itemText.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                     * 
                     * 
                     * inventoryRect.attachChild(itemText);
                     */
                    Text goldText = new Text(5, 0,
                            AssetLoaderUtil.mFontMENU, "Gold: "
                                    + UserData.getInstance()
                                            .getPlayerGold(),
                            mContext.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                    goldText.setPosition(50, 50);
                    goldText.setColor(Color.GREEN);

                    inventoryRect.attachChild(goldText);

                    if (UserData.getInstance().hasSword() == true) {

                        Text swordText = new Text(5, 0,
                                AssetLoaderUtil.mFontMENU, "Sword",
                                mContext.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                        swordText.setPosition(50, 75);
                        swordText.setColor(Color.RED);

                        inventoryRect.attachChild(swordText);

                    }

                    if (UserData.getInstance().hasAxe() == true) {

                        Text axeText = new Text(5, 0,
                                AssetLoaderUtil.mFontMENU, "Axe",
                                mContext.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                        axeText.setPosition(50, 95);
                        axeText.setColor(Color.RED);

                        inventoryRect.attachChild(axeText);

                    }

                    if (hasPotion == true) {

                        Text potionText = new Text(5, 0,
                                AssetLoaderUtil.mFontMENU, "Potion",
                                mContext.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                        potionText.setPosition(50, 115);
                        potionText.setColor(Color.BLUE);

                        inventoryRect.attachChild(potionText);

                    }

                } else {


                    inventory = false;

                    inventoryRect.setVisible(false);
                    // inventoryTitleText.setVisible(false);
                    // inventoryTitleText = null;

                    inventRect = false;

                }

                /*
                 * if (inventRect==false){
                 * 
                 * inventoryRect = new Rectangle(15,15,800,440,
                 * mContext.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                 * 
                 * inventoryRect.setColor(1, 1, 1, 0.8f);
                 * 
                 * hud.attachChild(inventoryRect);
                 * inventoryRect.setVisible(true);
                 * 
                 * inventRect = true;
                 */


                // this.setVisible(false);

            }
            return super.onAreaTouched(pAreaTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX,
                    pTouchAreaLocalY);
        }
    };
    hud.registerTouchArea(btn);
    hud.attachChild(btn);
```